# Creating a function to check codes against a master list

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to create a custom function, which I am not very experienced with at all, that would check a column that is comprised of item codes against a master list.  Then I would like (if possible) for the following steps to happen:

- Create a new column based on the list (see below)
- Populate that column with a value (expend) associated with the item code
- Optionally check a binary variable and given one of the conditions, send the value to a third column

The list is sort of a nested categorical grouping that looks like this

`code_list <- list((category_1 <- c("101", "102")), (category_2 <- c("201", "202", "203")))`

Formatted like that for about 70 "categories"
The codes to be checked are the codes being stored in the "category_" values.
Currently I have code that works in an `ifelse` within a  `mutate` function but the code is inefficient and not easily adjusted.  It looks like:

`mutate(category_2 = ifelse(code %in% category_2, value, 0), ...)`

for about 60 lines.

My questions are if a function like this is even possible, and if so what resources could be pointed to to get me started?

EDIT:

My attempt at an example

```r
table <- data.frame('id' = c("1001", "1002", "1003", "1004", "1005"), 
    'bin' = c("0", "0", "1", "1", "0"),
    'expend' = c(111, 222, 333, 444, 555),
    'code' = c("101", "102", "201", "202", "102")
    )

code_list <- list(
    (category_1 <- c("101", "102")),
    (category_2 <- c("201", "202", "203"))
    )

table2 <- table %>%
    mutate(
    category_1 = ifelse(code %in% category_1, expend, 0),
    category_2 = ifelse(code %in% category_2, expend, 0)
    )
```

But the `mutate` block goes on for 60+ lines.  Essentially I'd like to automate the `mutate` / `ifelse` function with an output like

```r
#     id bin expend code category_1 category_2
# 1 1001   0    111  101        111          0
# 2 1002   0    222  102        222          0
# 3 1003   1    333  201          0        333
# 4 1004   1    444  202          0        444
# 5 1005   0    555  102        555          0
```

Comment: You'll be more likely to get useful responses if you include a code block that includes example data and can be directly executed by others -- aka a [minimal working example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example)

Comment: Are your `category_*` vectors actually columns in a `data.frame`?  The `dplyr::mutate()` function is really designed for rectangular `data.frame`s, though since these are simply lists of equally long vectors, you might theoretically "trick" it into working on lists of irregular vectors.  In what context are you calling `mutate()`?

Comment: @Greg to begin the `category_*` vectors are "values" in a list and are of irregular length, but ideally they would each be made into their own columns (a wide form table is wanted).  I am calling `mutate()` to take a tbl_df with 6 columns and add a column for each `category_*` that are populated by their corresponding `code` values.  I'll try to post an example

Comment: This sounds like a fairly simple function? I would probably implement the list as a data frame and use a join... but it's hard to tell more without seeing sample input and desired output.

Comment: As lefft says, if you could provide a few rows of sample input corresponding to your sample `code_list`, a concrete example of your optional binary variable, and the desired output for the sample input, then I think we could constructively help.

Comment: @Justprintmoneylol Try this: `code_list |> tibble::enframe() |> tidyr::unnest_longer(value, indices_include = TRUE) |> tidyr::pivot_wider()`.  But first, you'll need to redefine `code_list` using proper syntax: `code_list <- list(` **`category_1 =`** `c("101", "102"),` **`category_2 =`** `c("201", "202", "203"))`. Note that **`=` is used** when assigning elements *within* a `list`.

Comment: I've done: `code_aggregator <- function(x){ code_list %>% tibble::enframe() %>% tidyr::unnest_longer(expend, indicies_include = TRUE) %>% tidyr::pivot_wider()}`   and then `table_wide <- code_aggregator(table)` and got `Error: object 'expend' not found`

Comment: @Justprintmoneylol I just provided that workflow so you could get `code_list` in a more convenient tabular form; not so you'd get your full result.

Comment: @Justprintmoneylol I just posted a **fully extensible** [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70088340) below.  It will work for any number of categories whose names are of the form `category_*`.

Comment: @Justprintmoneylol Did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70088340) work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a potential solution in the [**`tidyverse`**](https://www.tidyverse.org/):

## Solution

```
library(tidyverse)


# ...
# Code to generate 'code_list' and 'table'.
# ...


# Turn the list into a table:
code_table <- code_list %>%
  # Force into a table with list columns.
  enframe() %>%
  # Unnest those list columns and pivot them into a long format:
  # 'name' | 'value'
  unnest_longer(value, indices_include = TRUE) %>%
  # Pivot those long columns into a wide format, with blanks (NA) for missing values:
  # 'category_1' | 'category_2' | ...
  pivot_wider() %>% select(!value_id)

# Mesh the results into a single table and perform logic.
result <- table %>%
  # Do a CROSS JOIN.
  full_join(
    code_table,
    by = character()
  ) %>%
  # Operate within the scope of each record from the original 'table'.
  group_by(id) %>%
  # Perform logic to "roll up" each scope into a single row.
  summarize(
    # Preserve each record from the original table...
    across(
      # ...namely everything except the 'category_*' columns.
      !c(starts_with("category_")),
      first
    ),

    # Then hit ALL 'category_*' columns at once!
    across(
      starts_with("category_"),
      # Based on matches within scope, "roll up" each column into the desired scalar.
      ~ if_else(any(code %in% .), first(expend), 0)
    )
  )
```

## Result

Given a `code_list` like this

```
# A list defined with regular syntax.
code_list <- list(
  category_1 = c("101", "102"),
  category_2 = c("201", "202", "203")
)
```

along with a `table` like this

```
table <- data.frame(
  id = c("1001", "1002", "1003", "1004", "1005"), 
  bin = c("0", "0", "1", "1", "0"),
  expend = c(111, 222, 333, 444, 555),
  code = c("101", "102", "201", "202", "102")
)
```

this solution should yield the following `result`:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 6
  id    bin   expend code  category_1 category_2
  <chr> <chr>  <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1 1001  0        111 101          111          0
2 1002  0        222 102          222          0
3 1003  1        333 201            0        333
4 1004  1        444 202            0        444
5 1005  0        555 102          555          0
```

## Note

If your `code_list` has elements whose names deviate from the `category_*` convention, you'll need to replace every occurrence of [`starts_with`](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/starts_with.html)`("category_")` with [`matches`](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/starts_with.html)`("some regex")`, where `"some regex"` is a string defining a [regular expression](https://rdrr.io/r/base/regex.html) that matches exactly all the names in `code_list`.